# how to use jasmine spec runner with jest

Tags: jasmine, reactjs, jestjs

So, seeing that jest is built on top of jasmine, is there a way to use the jasmine spec runner to provide a more verbose result output for jest tests?  The spec runner sample makes it look easy enough, but i'm not sure what all the dependencies would  be.

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-1.3.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-1.3.0/jasmine.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/Player.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/Song.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/SpecHelper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/PlayerSpec.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest is meant to be run in a node environment and does some heavy wrapping of Jasmine, so it is not possible to use the spec runner via jest in the browser at the moment.

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/139) requesting this feature, so i'd suggest making your voice heard there.